# WPF - Call a Javascript in a WebBrowser

Tags: java, javascript, c#, html, wpf

I have a WebBrowser control in my WPF Descktop Aplication, i need to open this webbrowser in the form starts and make this code to do this:

```
public LibrasPlayer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LibrasPlayerWeb.LoadCompleted += webb_LoadCompleted;
}

void webb_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    LibrasPlayerWeb.InvokeScript("stop");
}
```

But when the code reach in "LibrasPlayerWeb.InvokeScript("stop");" have an error of (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)), this web page use Javascript to comunicate with a java engine to make a player of libras language, but all of InvokeScripts (Stop, Start, and other methods) give me this error.

Someone have any idea about how i can work with this?

Comment: and what is the relation with `java` tag?

Comment: " this web page use Javascript to comunicate with a java engine to make" Have a comunication in WPF with java methods using the javascript methods, if i send a "stop" to my javascript they send a stop to java.

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with MS stuffs, but if the `stop` is kinda a function, maybe you need to call it as `stop()`

Comment: Nope because i'm invoking a script from javascript, with other process, other javascripts this system works, but in this his don't work, and the diference is the java call from javascript.